# Trouble getting Java flash policy server work

Tags: java, file, policy

I'm trying to create a game server for flash, but I'm stuck trying to send a policy file from my Java server to the Flash game.

The server got message

```
<policy-file-request/>\0
```

as well but returning an xml back to the game is not work.

Here is my game server code when getting and returning messages

```
    if (message.equals("<policy-file-request/>" + '\0')) {
        StringBuffer policyBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        policyBuffer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><cross-domain-policy>");
        policyBuffer.append("<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />");
        policyBuffer.append("</cross-domain-policy>");
        String returnPolicy = policyBuffer.toString() + '\0';
        //byte[] returnPolicyBytes = returnPolicy.getBytes();
        System.out.println("Returning cross-domain-policy...\n" + returnPolicy);
        //packet.socket.getOutputStream().write(returnPolicyBytes, 0, returnPolicyBytes.length);
        //packet.socket.getOutputStream().flush();
        packet.out.println(returnPolicy);
        packet.out.flush();
        return;
    }
```

** "packet" is my socket client wrapper object which have "out" field that is a object of "PrintWritter" class **

I don't know why my flash game can't receive an xml message (always timed out),
Can I increase more time to request policy file ?,
May I have to create new policy server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I have to create new policy server and listen on port 843 instead using game server to responding with policy messages.